# Can't connect to Sharepoint Online with Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm having a problem with sharepoint designer. I want to connect to Sharepoint site hosted in O365. When I click "Open Site", I get prompted for credentials. I enter my credentials and I'm immedietaly asked for them again. It doesn't matter if I repeat it, or not - it's like an infinite loop.

No MFA is enabled for this account.

This account is both Sharepoint admin (global admin to be specific) and an admin for this site

I don't have any updates on my computer waiting.

I have enabled custom scripts on Sharepoint for this O365 tenant. I've waited for over 24 hours for this to work.

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this question on reddit as well, and a user by the name of u/RobAkaCptnTryhrd posted a solution to my problem:

"I was able resolve this for myself by removing Registry keys: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity FederationCacheExpiration  FederationProvider

And adding this one:HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity add Dword EnaleADAL 1"

Comment: ... add Dword EnableADAL ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions on site collection level to make sure it allows SharePoint Designer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2592376/manage-permissions-and-control-access-to-sharepoint-designer?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contributions, Please do not only provide links as answers. If the link breaks the answer will be of very little help, it is better to add the important steps from your links and add it as a reference  :)